# jetty access.log is no longer logging

Tags: jetty

I have enabled Jetty Access Logs in production and things were going great, until today.  Today the access logs appear to no longer be taking data, even though the service itself is running without incident.  I suspect there is something I don't understand about the "retainDays" property.  Here is the excerpt from etc/jetty.xml that sets up the logging...

```
<!-- Built-in Jetty AccessLog log -->
<Ref id="AccessLog">
  <Set name="requestLog">
    <New id="RequestLogImpl" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.NCSARequestLog">
      <Arg><SystemProperty name="jetty.logs" default="/data/logs"/>/dm-app1_access.log</Arg>
      <Set name="retainDays">7</Set>
      <Set name="append">true</Set>
      <Set name="extended">false</Set>
      <Set name="logLatency">true</Set>
      <Set name="LogTimeZone">GMT</Set>
    </New>
  </Set>
</Ref>
```

Why did logging seemingly stop when this kid hit the retainDays value?  I expected it to just truncate and continue on logging to /data/logs/dm-app1_access.log.

Comment: This is kind-of Jetty Documentation fail.  The http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/RequestLog does not make clear the relationship between retainDays and "yyyy_mm_dd".  If you read the source code of NCSARequestLog.java and the JavaDoc for RolloverFileOutputStream you learn that the string "yyyy_mm_dd" IS REQUIRED to get anything like rollover.  It does not appear that you can change this at all.  Ugh.

Comment: we take patches and suggestions on how to improve both of those things :)

Comment: My suggestion would be that this access log should work in exactly the same manner as logback's RollingFileAppender.  This would allow me to tail -F a fixed filename and the logging mechanism would handle the rollover.  It took 4 hours and a sourcecode deep dive to realize that 'yyyy_mm_dd' is just a place holder for the <Set name="filenameDateFormat">yyyyMMdd</Set> actual SimpleDateFormat value to be applied in RolloverFileOutputStream.setFile().  Principle of least surprise, this adventure was not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logging stopped because my filename did not include the "yyyy_mm_dd" placeholder.  The configuration found to work complete with a logfile naming format similar how we have our logback RollingFileAppenders going is like...

```
<!-- Built-in Jetty AccessLog log -->
<Ref id="AccessLog">
  <Set name="requestLog">
    <New id="RequestLogImpl" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.NCSARequestLog">
      <Set name="filename"><SystemProperty name="jetty.logs" default="./logs"/>/access.yyyy_mm_dd.log</Set>
      <Set name="filenameDateFormat">yyyyMMdd</Set>
      <Set name="retainDays">3</Set>
      <Set name="append">true</Set>
      <Set name="extended">false</Set>
      <Set name="logLatency">true</Set>
      <Set name="LogTimeZone">GMT</Set>
    </New>
  </Set>
</Ref>
```

...this gets access logfiles created like logs/access.20120718.log.  The big learning moment came when I figured out that 'yyyy_mm_dd' in the "filename" property is just a placeholder for the actual SimpleDateFormat contained in the "filenameDateFormat" property.

Comment: three cheers for the self answer, even though it didn't help me :)